# How to create index to support multiple queries simultaneously in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, mongodb-indexes

I have 3 different fields `a`, `b`, `c` in my collection `X`, where:

`a` -> short string/keyword, `b` -> url, `c` -> date

I have 2 queries which need `a, b` and `a, c` respectively.

My question is,

How to index properly to optimize both queries.

---

I have considered:

1) Two compound index of `a+b` and `a+c`

2) create 3 single key indexes for `a`, `b`, `c` and rely on index intersection.

3) create a compound index for `a+b` and a single index for `c`, and hope that `c` and prefix `a` will optimize the second query.

4) create a compound index for `a+b+c` (not sure about this)

What is the best solution and why?

Comment: What kind of queries are these? The date is probably a range and returns many records? The keyword and URL are exact match returning many (keyword) and very few (URL)?

Comment: well, the first query that uses `keyword + url` basically an upsert operation. And `date` is a range as you mentioned and so `date+keyword` returns many records.

Comment: Both `1` and `4` seem reasonable.